# Pointed maps on S^n don't associate under #.

Tags: algebraic-topology

My topology professor gave us the following definition: for two pointed maps, $f,g:S^n\to (X,x_0)$, we may regard the functions as maps on $[0,1]^n$ that are constant on the boundary. We then define $f\# g (s_1,...,s_n) = f(s_1,...,2s_n-1)$ if $\frac{1}{2}\leq s_n \leq 1$ and $=g(s_1,...,2s_n)$ if $0 \leq s_n \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Then he made the comment that this operation was not associative on individual functions, but was on their homotopy classes, and procedeeded to prove that homotopy groups are groups.

I have had a terrible time finding a counter example to show this is not associative. I thought to make $n=2, X=[0,1]$ and then pick two constant functions, and even that has been too difficult to find a formula for the third that works. Why is this $\#$ function not associative?

Comment: the way you associate the product of functions f,g,h will change which part of the interval [0,1] you use each of f,g,h.  To make it associative up to homotopy you use a reparametrization.

Comment: Yes. I've written that all out, and tried to find functions f,g,h that, when f#(g#h) and (f#g)#h are evaluated at even a single point in the domain, give different outputs. I'm not worried about making work for homotopy classes, but rather making it not work for individual functions.

Comment: I've given an example as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Take for example $n=1, X=S^1, $ and $  x_0=0$, where we are thinking of $X$ as $[0,1]$ with endpoints identified.  Define $f(x)=x,g(x)=2x,h(x)=3x$, each reduced mod $1$.

$(f\#(g\#h))(\frac{3}{8})=(g\#h)(\frac{3}{4})=g(\frac{1}{2})=1=0$

$((f\#g)\#h)(\frac{3}{8})=h(\frac{3}{4})=\frac{9}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

I've found another example, finally.
By definition,
f# (g# h)(x) = \begin{cases} 
      f(2x-1), &\text{if}~\frac{1}{2}\leq x \leq 1 \\
      g (4x-1), &\text{if}~ \frac{1}{4}\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}\\
      h(4x), &\text{if}~ 0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{4}.
      \end{cases}
while 
 (f# g)# h(x) = \begin{cases} 
      f(4x-3), &\text{if}~\frac{3}{4}\leq x \leq 1 \\
      g (4x-2)), &\text{if}~ \frac{1}{2}\leq x \leq \frac{3 }{4}\\
      h(2x), &\text{if}~ 0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}.
      \end{cases}
Let $$f(x) = |x-\frac{1}{2}|,$$ $$g(x) = \frac{1}{2},$$ $$h(x) = -|x-\frac{1}{2}| +1.$$
For the hash functions to be well-defined, we need $h(1) = g(0),$ and $g(1) = f(0)$. Additionally, each of $f,g,$ and $h$ must have the same value at 0 and 1 to satisfy the boundary condition. Thus, we need to check that $f(0) = f(1) = g(0) = g(1) = h(0) = h(1) = \frac{1}{2}$, so that the maps are pointed. This is easily obtained from the above formulas. Lastly, we need to check that the hash function is not associative. Take $x = \frac{1}{4}$. Then $(f\#g)\# h (\frac{1}{4}) = h(\frac{1}{2}) = 1$ while  $f\# (g\# h)(\frac{1}{4}) = h(1) =\frac{1}{2},$ so these functions are not the same. Therefore, $\#$ is not associative.